# mysql transaction commited only partly

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I keep seeing what appears to be a partly-commited transaction using innodb tables:

1. all my tables use innodb as a backend
2. mysql  version:  5.5.31-0ubuntu0.13.04.1-log
3. python web application based on uwsgi, each http request is wrapped in a separate transaction that is either commited or rolled back depending on whether an exception is generated during the request
4. each request-serving process uses a single mysql connection that is not shared across processes
5. a couple of other processes connect to the DB to perform background tasks that are all wrapped in transactions
6. transactions are all created and tracked through a sqlalchemy middleware which is configured to not change the default mysql isolation level which is REPEATABLE READ

Despite all this (I triple checked each item a couple of times), my DB appears to contain half-commited transactions:
 1. 2 tables A and B with A that contains a foreign key to B (there are no constraints defined in the DB)
 2. A contains a valid row that points to a non-existent row in B. 
 3. B contains rows with id + 1 and id - 1.
 4. both rows in both tables are inserted within a single transaction

To summarize, I can't see what I could have possibly done wrong. I can't imagine I am hitting a bug in the mysql storage backend so, I am looking for help on how I could debug this further and what assumption I made above is the most likely to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while but it appears that the transaction was automatically rolled back by error 1213 (deadlock) and 1205 (lock wait timeout exceeded). It did not help that these errors were caught in some internal middleware that tried to execute again the statement that failed instead of forwarding the error up to the transaction layer where the entire transaction could be retried or abandoned as a whole. The result was that the code would keep on executing normally under the assumption that the ongoing transaction was still ongoing while it had been rolled back by the mysql server.